# Redirect user after logout

Tags: redirect, login, logout

I am trying to create an unsubscribe page for my members, but in order to see the unsubscribe form, they have to be logged out, so the first link is:

```
/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=ba51bbcdc3.
```

Once they are logged out, I need them redirected to the unsubscribe form, but I can't just set up a forward, because this is also the login page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`wp_logout_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url) template tag to generate a logout link. You can specify the URL that the user will be redirected to as the first pramiter:

```
wp_logout_url( 'http://example.com' );
```

The above code will generate a URL that looks a bit like this: `/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=ba51bbcdc3&redirect_to=http://example.com/unsubscribe`. You can make it into a link like so:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url( 'unsubscribe' ) ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout & Unsubscribe</a>
```

---

If you want to use this in a page or post, you need to create a shortcode:

```
function wpse_77939_unsubscribe_link() {
    return sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" title="Logout">Logout & Unsubscribe</a>',
        wp_logout_url( home_url( 'unsubscribe' ) )
    );
add_shortcode( 'unsubscribe-link', 'wpse_77939_unsubscribe_link' );
```

You can then add `[unsubscribe-link]` to a post or page where you want the link to appear.

---

If you're redirecting to another website besides your own, you need to add this code to your `functions.php` file (replace `example.com` with the domain of the site):

```
add_filter( 'allowed_redirect_hosts','wpse_77938_allowed_redirect_hosts' );
function wpse_77938_allowed_redirect_hosts( $allowed ) {
    $allowed[] = 'example.com';
    return $allowed;
}
```

Comment: This answer expands on @WordPress Kid's post

Answer (score 1):

Use this code if you are using it at menu at menu manger

```
http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=http://www.example.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress includes a template tag which you can use: [`wp_logout_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url). It's a few simple lines of code if you want to redirect users to another URL after they sign out.

I [wrote a tutorial](http://wordpresskid.blogspot.in/2012/11/logout-and-redirect-to-new-url.html) late last year on how to use this template tag. In summary, you need to create a filter in `functions.php` and then create a Logout link in `sidebar.php`.

If you're redirecting to another website besides your own, you need to add this code to your `functions.php` file (replace `example.com` with the domain of the site):

```
add_filter( 'allowed_redirect_hosts','wpse_77938_allowed_redirect_hosts' );
function wpse_77938_allowed_redirect_hosts($link) {
    $link[] = 'example.com';
    return $link;
}
```

You then need to add this line to your `sidebar.php` file or anywhere you can execute PHP:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( 'http://example.com' ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Please explain how to do it as part of your answer

Comment: Done @bungeshea.